# How to resync the linked proxy to incorporate changes in the main file

Tags: rigging, linked-data

Let's suppose I had a rig(Root) parented to a mesh X in a file named blend_1. Now I link the whole collection in which those two are to another blender file(Blend_2). Now, I make a proxy for Root, Then I make two actions and while animating  I discover that there are weight painting issues in Root, so I decided that instead of Root being a parent to mesh X I want it to be parented to mesh Y. So, I unparent mesh X and parent the Root to mesh Y in blend_1, But the problem is those parenting changes are not incorporated in blend_2.
Is there a way to resync proxy such that my current animations for the Root can be used on the mesh Y as well?

I am using blender 2.91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found- roughly speaking- is to close both the files and open them again hereby resyncing.
Another more appropriate way is:
Outliner change Display mode  to blender file
Then you will see the linked file-> right click you will get options to relocate, reload.